# Problems in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have already done `pip install pyinstaller` and also have tried `pip freeze` and verified that pyinstaller is installed.

When I type:

`pyinstaller install acgui.py` (some other file) in Command Prompt

I get :

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

PLS HELP....

Comment: You need to have python installed so its Scripts folder is in your path. With Python 3.8.3 (and at least for 3.8.x not sure about all earlier) on Windows it's an option to put python on the path - perhaps you didn't do that?

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-pyinstaller This might help

Comment: go to scripts folder and pyinstaller folder open cmd and Run Pyinstaller.exe from there . it should work